# URL changes set by react-router-dom 'useSearchParams' are not maintained when set by mui 'Tabs' component's onChange callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I would like to set a tab navigation component based on the search parameter named `tab`.

If my url is `example.com?tab=test2`, I would like my navigation bar to display the `test2` item as selected.

I'm using [mui Tabs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/) component for this.

I'm able to successfully *set* my `Tab` state by *getting* the search parameter with `searchParams.get('tab')`, however, when I set the `tab` property, it's only reflected for a moment, before being overwritten with a null state (and so the URL is changed to have no search parameters).

I've tried to add a null checker to set a default search parameter, but it isn't "keeping."

What's very strange is that if I simply set search params using plain buttons, the changes "keep."

I've created a [codesandbox minimal implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-vaughan-3i8lof?file=/src/App.tsx) to demonstrate, however, in short, my change function, that gets invoked both within the mui `Tabs` component's `onChange` callback as well as my simple button `onClick` callbacks, looks like this:

```
  const handleChange = (event: SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
    searchParams.set("tab", newValue);
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  };
```

And the value is initially set upon component instantiation (I believe based on console log experiments) with:

```
const PartsTabNav = () => {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  let queryTab = searchParams.get("tab");
```

**Why do my buttons change the URL, but not the MUI Tabs component's onChange, even though both invoke the same function?**

EDIT: It seems it might actually have something to do with the `<Link>` component based on my debugging.

The full example code is below:

```
import { Grid, Tab, Tabs } from "@mui/material";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { SyntheticEvent, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useSearchParams, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const tabOptions = [
  {
    label: "Test1",
    route: "test1"
  },
  {
    label: "Test2",
    route: "test2"
  }
];

const PartsTabNav = () => {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  let queryTab = searchParams.get("tab");
  queryTab = queryTab ? queryTab : "test1";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!queryTab) {
      searchParams.set("tab", "test1");
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
  }, [searchParams, setSearchParams, queryTab]);


  const handleChange = (event: SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
    searchParams.set("tab", newValue);
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e, "test1");
                }}
              >
                one
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e, "test2");
                }}
              >
                two
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Tabs
            value={queryTab}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            aria-label="Tabs"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {tabOptions.map((tab, index) => (
              <Tab
                key={index}
                component={Link}
                to="#"
                label={tab.label}
                value={tab.route}
              />
            ))}
          </Tabs>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PartsTabNav />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from using `Link` (from react-router) as a `component` prop for `Tab`. There was some default click handling that was happening that was causing a page refresh. Changing to the below, fixed the issue.

```
{tabOptions.map((tab, index) => (
    <Tab
        key={index}
        icon={tab.icon}
        label={tab.label}
        value={tab.route}
    />
))}
```